# Bar Chart outside bounds and mouseover event issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, mouseover, dimple.js

1. Here is my dimple.js code, the bar chart that it produces is outside the bounds and touching Y-axis.
2. Mouseover event is not changing the color of the bars.
   Below is the image

   ```
   var myChart2 = new dimple.chart(svg,data);
       myChart2.setBounds(750,50,550,250);    
       var x = myChart2.addTimeAxis( "x", "date", "%m/%d/%Y", "%d-%b");
       x.floatingBarWidth = 21;
       var y2= myChart2.addMeasureAxis("y","callperorder");
       var y1= myChart2.addMeasureAxis("y","calls");


       var bars = myChart2.addSeries("or", dimple.plot.bar,[x,y2]);

       var lines= myChart2.addSeries("cl", dimple.plot.line,[x,y1]);


       lines.lineMarkers= true;       

       myChart2.addLegend(750, 20, 300, 20, "right");

       myChart2.assignColor("cl","rgb(99,39,29)");
       myChart2.assignColor("or","rgb(99,89,219)");


       myChart2.draw();

      \\MOUSEOVER EVENT       
       bars.addEventHandler("mouseover", function( {d3.select(this).style("fill","green")});
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the event handler before calling draw if you want to use the dimple method.  Alternatively you could use the d3 method after draw.

```
bars.shapes.on("mouseover", function () {...});
```

NB. There's also a typo in your event declaration, it's missing the closing bracket after `function (`.

In order to avoid overlapping the edge of the chart you will need to manually set the x bounds:

```
x.overrideMin = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse("12/31/2014");
x.overrideMax = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse("01/11/2015");
```

Using whatever values you want of course;

Comment: I have added the event handler before myChart.draw(); nothing happens. If I use bars.shapes...... everything works but I lose the default tooltip.

Comment: There is one more thing, If i override min and max , I get a feeling by looking at the chart that nothing happened on 31st dec and 11th Jan. Isn't there a way to just move them in, like collapse them by few cms.

Comment: Either solution will remove the current tooltip behaviour, you can manually invoke the dimple tooltip:  bars.shapes.on("mouseover", function (e) { dimple._showBarTooltip(e, this, chart, bars); });

Comment: Regarding spacing, it sounds like you might be better using a category axis on x

Comment: You can keep the default tooltip behavior by namespacing the event in the on handler, ie "bars.shapes.on("mouseover.my_handler")". (http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)  John you may want to namespace the events in the Dimple source going forward to avoid that